# Compute flex element width before rendering using JS

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I have a flex-box with an undefined number of cards inside it.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 210px
}
```

I must decide how many cards put inside my box, the number of cards displayed will be the right amount to fill exactly two rows.

```
===== is a card

---------------------
| ===== ===== ===== |
| ===== ===== ===== |
---------------------
```

This means, that, with a `.box` of `630px`, I will display 6 cards. `(630 / 210) * 2 = 6`

To compute the cards number per row I'm using this code:

```
getCardsPerRow() {
  let listWidth = box.clientWidth

  // use flex-basis width to compute the initial number of cards per row
  let cardsNumber = Math.floor(listWidth / 210)

  // add to the cards width the left amount of available space (distributing it evenly)
  let cardWidth = Math.floor(listWidth / cardsNumber + listWidth % cardsNumber)

  // divide listWidth by the width of a single card to get the total
  return Math.floor(listWidth / cardWidth)
}
```

It works well on most of the situations. But with some widths I get a wrong number.

For example, with a `box` wide `1132px`, I get `4`, even if flexbox will put on a single row `5` cards.

Trying another approach, if I compute the cards number doing `Math.floor(listWidth / 210)`, I'll get a wrong result with (for example) a `box` wide `1075px`.
It should return 4 (according to the flexbox CSS result), but instead it returns 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding `listWidth % cardsNumber`? I think `listWidth / cardsNumber`should be enough.

Comment: I've already tried your suggested way (it's the second attempt in my post)

Comment: Umm, `floor(1075 / 210)` is 5. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Exactly, but when I then render the page, the row contains 5 elements (instead of the 4 expected)

Comment: Ok seems like the problem was the margin on the elements... such a stupid error

Answer (score 0):

Your math is incorrect, as pointed out in the comments.  Let's walk through it:

```
const listWidth = 1132;
const cardsNumber = Math.floor(listWidth / 210);
```

At this point, `cardsNumber` is 5 (from 5.3905.)  Obviously, there is extra space.

```
const cardWidth = Math.floor(listWidth / cardsNumber + listWidth % cardsNumber);
```

This is where things go wrong.  `listWidth / cardsNumber` is `1132 / 5`, or `226.4`.  `listWidth % cardsNumber` or `1132 % 5` is 2.

This basically guarantees that you'll calculate a `cardWidth` value that is either equal to (if `listWidth % cardsNumber` is 0) or slightly greater than the available width.  Note that with 1130, it would be equal.

The other problem is when things flex, which might be why you added this mistaken accounting.  `flex: 1 210px;` means that grow and shrink are both allowed.

What happens if a box becomes 250px?  Well, 250 + 210 * 4 = 1090, so it still fits inside 1132.

What happens if ALL boxes become 250px?  Now we have 1250, which is too big.  Now we only have 4 in the first row.

As you can see, you need to know the minimum and maximum width of the boxes to properly calculate this.  If you're sure they will all be fine at 210px, then just use `cardsNumber` and set `flex-grow` to 0.

Otherwise, you can sum the widths of the next `cardsNumber` boxes, and see if it's less than `listWidth`.  If it isn't, then that row has lost a card (possibly multiple.)

Another approach is to add the cards to the box one at a time, and check the `offsetTop` of each one.  When it increases for the second time, you broke the second row.  Remove the last added item, and you have two neatly packed rows (as neatly as you can get.)